# 302 redirect while downloading Jfrog PHP private artifact

Tags: php, composer-php, artifactory, jfrog-cli

```
Downloading (connecting...)
Downloading (connecting...)
Update failed (The \
"https://abc.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/composer/php-local/direct-dists/@abc/framework/abc_code.zip" \
file could not be downloaded, got redirect without Location (HTTP/1.1 302 Found))
Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]?
```

This was working earlier suddenly stopped.

In browser also working fine. Only while doing `composer update` or `composer install`

- Composer version: 1.5.6
- VagrantBox: 7.0
- PHP: 5.5
- Host OS: MacOS
- Vagrant : 2.3
- VirtualBox  : 7.2
- Scientific Linux release 6.5 ( CentOS )

Comment: Can you add details about the client that is being used? What version? What command?

Comment: This is general `composer install` I am doing. added some more details

Comment: "This was working earlier" - what happened since then? Also, PHP 5.5 is horribly outdated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got solved by upgrading Composer version to 2.

Jfrog throwing error when there is composer version 1.x while pulling Artifact.

Sometime an OS doesn't easily upgrade to Composer 2 due to missing CA certificates.

Can follow below steps:

1. `cd /etc/pki/tls/certs`
2. check `ca-bundle.crt` file is there or not: `file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`
3. `sudo curl https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt -k` run this command to download the [CA certificates extracted from Mozilla](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html).
4. upgrade composer using following this page https://getcomposer.org/download/ :

   ```
   php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
   php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
   php composer-setup.php
   php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
   ```

   *(always take the latest version from the [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/) as it changes from time to time)*